# Unable to Install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: windows-10, installation, sql-server, parallels

I'm trying to install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express (SSMSE).
version: SQLServer2005_SSMSEE_x64.msi

I get the error:

"The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 29506."

I tried troubleshooting this error with instructions to use the command prompt.

https://www.linglom.com/administration/solved-error-29506-when-installing-microsoft-sql-server-manament-studio-express-on-windows-vista-or-windows-seven/

When I try the command prompt I get this installation package could not be opened.

Environment: Parallels Windows 10 home 64bit on MAc

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which version of SSMS you are installing.  **Honestly it sounds like the file is corrupt.**  You should also indicate which version of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound done edit!

Comment: You didn't indicate which version of Windows 10 Home you are using.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2005 (ie a 14 year old database) wasnt compatible with Windows 8 so I doubt it will work properly under Windows 10. You could try compatibility mode to see if it will allow the installer to run but i'm dubious on that.

You could try installing a newer version of SMS, they are generally backwards compatible, but im not sure how far back. You might be able to find a version of SMS that runs on Windows 10 and will talk to a 2005 instance?

One more thing - if your using SMS 2005 i presume your wanting to connect to some legacy operating system?  If the database lives on an older version of Windows, you might not be able to login due to no compatible SSL/TLS available which is required to authenticate remotely.

Disclaimer - im not a Mac user, I dont know if that adds further issues.